# How to design a square cross word?

Tags: android, user-interface

I don't know how to have a square with 36 edit text cells in with a horizontal number list on the top and a vertical number list beside.
the main part is getting the device width resolution and set the height equal to width. and also the square should fill the screen width.
i wrote a class extends linear layout...

please help me with my code...

```
public class crossWordLayout extends LinearLayout {

int screenWidth = GlobalClass.getScreenWidth();

public crossWordLayout(Context context) {
    super(context);
    firstInitialize(context);
}
public crossWordLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    firstInitialize(context);
}



private void firstInitialize(Context context) {
    this.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams firstLayoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(screenWidth / 10, screenWidth);
    this.setLayoutParams(firstLayoutParams);
    this.context = context;
    this.height = 4;
    this.width = 4;


    LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0, screenWidth, width);
    LinearLayout templateLinearLayout = new LinearLayout(context);
    templateLinearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    templateLinearLayout.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
    this.templateLinearLayout = templateLinearLayout;
    this.addView(templateLinearLayout);

    layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 0, 1);
    LinearLayout balaNumber = new LinearLayout(context);
    balaNumber.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
    this.balaNumber = balaNumber;
    templateLinearLayout.addView(balaNumber);

    layoutParams = new LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 0, height + 1);
    LinearLayout jadvalLinearLayout = new LinearLayout(context);
    jadvalLinearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    jadvalLinearLayout.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
    this.sellols = jadvalLinearLayout;
    templateLinearLayout.addView(jadvalLinearLayout);


    layoutParams = new LayoutParams(0, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1);
    LinearLayout kenarNumber = new LinearLayout(context);
    kenarNumber.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    kenarNumber.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
    this.kenarNumber = kenarNumber;
    this.addView(kenarNumber);
   }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using the GridLayout? I don't have a lot of experience but perhaps if you extend GridLayout, then populate each cell with an editText field, that might be easier to manage?

Comment: i don't know how to use gridLayout...

Answer (score 0):

I would use a GridLayout with an ArrayAdapter and populate with a single letter editText at it cell

Answer (score 0):

Here is some code for a simple `GridLayout`. The `GridLayout` will be inside of whatever layout container you have set for this `Activity`.
your_layout.xml

```
<GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/crosswordGrid"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:columnCount="6"
    android:rowCount="6"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth" >
</GridLayout>
```

In your `Activity` that creates the Crossword you will want this code:

```
public void setupGrid() {
    GridLayout crossword = (GridLayout) findViewById(R.id.crosswordGrid);
    for(int row = 0; row < 6; row++) {
        for(int col = 0; col < 6; col++) {
            crossword.addView(new EditText(this), new GridLayout.LayoutParams(GridLayout.spec(row, GridLayout.CENTER),
                    GridLayout.spec(col, GridLayout.CENTER)));
        }   //for the Context that's required in new EditText(), you might have to do this.getContext(). I'm not really able to test this code out
    }
}
```

This probably doesn't have everything you'll need for your specific implementation, but it should at least get you started in the right direction if you want to use a GridLayout. Best of luck!